# Is it possible to detect when the console is closed in Java?

Tags: java, jar, console-application

I am writing a program that will be saved as a .JAR and run from the console. I want the program to save to a file whenever a user closes its window, but I don't know if you can detect the window being closed. I know I could use a WindowListener in JFrame to detect the Close Event, run the save function, then end the program, but with what the program is and how I set it up I don't really want to do that. I am running on Windows 8, if that makes a difference.